# Training neural network with BFGS quasi newton using pybrain

Tags: neural-network, pybrain, training-data

I would like to train a neural network using pybrain and i use

```
trainer=BackpropTrainer(n,ds, learningrate=0.01, momentum=0.9,verbose=True)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence(ds)
```

The training using trainUntilConvergence(ds) takes time to converge even for few examples as it uses gradient descent. Is there a function or wrapper to use BFGS quasi newton algorithm for my training in using pybrain?

Thank you